# merged linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

This question was asked to me in an interview:
There are two header of two linked lists.
There is a merged linked list in c where in the second linked list is merged into the first one at some point.
How could we identify the merging point and what is the complexity of finding that point ?

Could anybody please help?

Comment: I think we need clarification: Is one list completely contained within the other, or do two separate lists join, like the arms of a Y?

Comment: @carl.. second linked list is merged into the first one `at some point`. this clearlt clarifies that the second linked list is inserted into  the first one at some point in the middle.is this not enough?

Answer (score 3):

O(n)

```
search = list1->header;
if (mixed->header == list1->header) search = list2->header;

while (mixed->next != search) mixed = mixed->next;
```

---

*Edit: new name for variables and a few comments*

```
/* search is what we want to find. Here it's the head of `list2` */
search = list2->header;
/* unless the merging put `list2` first; then we want to search for `list1` */
if (mixed->header == list2->header) search = list1->header;

/* assume (wrongly) that the header for the mixed list is the merge point */
mergepoint = mixed->head;

/* traverse the mixed list until we find the pointer we're searching */
while (mergepoint->next != search) mergepoint = mergepoint->next;
/* mergepoint now points to the merge point */
```

Comment: This algorithm is broken. It assumes that if 1 element in the combined linked list is equal to the first element of linked list 2, then the whole list must be equal. 

You also can't look at the memory positions because node 1 of linked list 2 with have previous_node set to null whereas the combined list probably won't as there will be bits of linked list 1 in there.

Comment: All objects in the pseudo code above (`search`, `list1->header`, `list2->header`, `mixed->header`, `mixed`) are **pointers**. If any of them are repeated you have a circular list.

Comment: @pmg: You're totally right. I was also thinking about searching for the content of list 2 inside list 1, but comparing the pointers is correct.

Comment: Pointers is wrong. I'll explain. Let's say that list2 is in the middle of list one. If to create combined_list you point directly at the nodes of list1 or list2 then you corrupt those lists. According to your algorithm, if list2.head == combined_list.element(n) then list2.tail.next would no longer point to null, it would point to the next element of list1. This would've corrupted your lists completely therefore to create combined_list you can only copy content and not pointers.

Comment: But how is the complexity calculated?

Comment: Just to be clear, you can't use pointer comparison and the algorithm above without corrupting list2 (and for that matter, maybe even list1).

Comment: Just another funny thing, if you do go on assuming that the pointers are actually reused, then if list1 contains list2 then list2 is always necessarily a suffix of list1 because you end up corrupting list2 with the end contents of list1. 
I'm pretty sure the interviewer did not meant this.

Comment: @rui: how do you merge `1, 3, 5, 7` and `2, 4, 6` (values, not pointers)?

Comment: Not sure I follow what you mean - do you want me to give you permutations of different merges? If I merge list2 into list1 there are 5 different combinations. If I merge list1 into list2 there are 4 combinations.

Comment: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7` is possible, right? Where's the merge point?

Comment: Nope, that's not possible - basically there you just blended and scrambled both lists together.

Comment: Ah! @rui ... I think I see what we're thinking differently. To me, a `linked list` is ordered, `merging` implies sorting. Maybe the question isn't as well defined as it could :)

Comment: Some examples: 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 7 if you merge list2 into list1. 2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 7, 6 if you merge list1 into list2.

Comment: Yeah, I think we agree on that, we're kind of thinking about two different problems. :)

Comment: @pmg: I certainly would not think a linked list is ordered because sorting linked lists is very inefficient. Still, I think your solution is the easiest one and would have solved the interviewer's question.

Comment: Well ... if you "go to the trouble of creating a linked list" (as opposed to an array), at least keep it sorted (in whatever way is appropriate [stacks, for example, are inherently unordered; but you are not going to merge 2 stacks]). What's the benefit of using an unordered linked list over an array (malloc/realloc/free is needed)?

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** This assumes the Y-shaped joining of two linked lists as described better in Steve Jessop's post. But I think the description of the problem is sufficiently ambiguous that various interpretations are possible, of which this is only one.

---

This can be done with a single pass through one list plus a partial pass through the other. In other words, it's O(n).

Here's my proposed algorithm:

Create a hashmap. (Yes, this is busywork in C if you don't have a library handy for it).
The keys will be pointers to the items in List1 (i.e. the head pointer and each link).
The values will be integers denoting the position, i.e. distance from the head of List1.

Run through List1, keeping track of the position, and hash all your pointers and positions.

Run through List2, keeping track of the position, and find the first pointer that occurs in the hashmap.

At this point, you'll know the position in List2 of the first node common to both lists.
The hashmap entry will also contain the position in List1 of that same node.
That will nicely identify your merge point.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean you have a Y-shape, like this:

list1: A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F

list2: X -> Y -> Z -> E -> F

Where A .. Z are singly-linked list nodes. We want to find the "merge point" E, which is defined to be the first node appearing in both lists. Is that correct?

If so, then I would attach the last node of list2 (F) to the first node of list2 (X). This turns list2 into a loop:

list2 : X -> Y -> Z -> E -> F -> X -> ...

But more importantly:

list1 : A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F -> X -> Y -> Z -> E -> ...

This reduces the question to [a previously-solved problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Tortoise_and_hare), which can be solved in O(n) time and O(1) additional storage.

But reading your question, another possibility is that by "merge" you mean "insert". So you have two lists like this:

list1: A -> B -> C

list2: D -> E -> F

and then another completely separate list:

list3: A -> B -> D -> E -> F -> C

where this time, A .. F are the values contained in the list, not the nodes themselves.

If the values are all different, you just need to search list3 for D (or for the later of D and A, if you don't know which list it was that was copied into the other). Which seems like a pointless question. If values can be repeated, then you have to check for the full sequence of list2 inside list3. But just because you find "DEF" doesn't mean that's where list2 was inserted - maybe "DEF" already occurred several times in list1 beforehand, and you've just found the first of those. For instance if I insert "DEF" into "ABCDEF", and the result is "ABCDEFDEF", then did I insert at index 3 or at index 6? There's no way to tell, so the question can't be answered.

So, in conclusion, I don't understand the question. But I might have answered it anyway.

Comment: Your question is very relevant, and I wish we'd hear from the OP about it. Alas, he hasn't been heard from in the last 3 hours.

Comment: Ah well, maybe he'll be back later or tomorrow, to check for answers. I'm hoping it is the Y-shape, because it's very neat that it turns into cycle-finding, and I'm feeling clever for spotting it :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the question means list2 contained in list1 (that is list2 points somewhere in the middle of list1), then it is easy - just walk list1 and compare pointers until you reach list2.

However such interpretation does not make much sense, because by inserting list2 into the list1 (like 1 1 2 2 1), you would also modify list2 - the last 1 becomes part of list2.

So I will assume the **question is about the Y shape**:

list1: A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F

list2: X -> Y -> Z -> E -> F

This can be solved using hashtable as Carl suggested.

Solution **without a hashtable** would be this:

1. Walk list1 and disconnect all its pointers as you go
2. Walk list2. When it ends, you've reached the junction point
3. Repair the pointers in list1

Disconnecting and repairing pointers in list1 can be done easily using recursion:

```
Diconnect(node)
{
    if (node->next == NULL)
      walk list2 to its end, that is the solution, remember it
    else
    {
       tmp = node->next;
       node->next = NULL;
       Disconnect(tmp);
       node->next = tmp;  // repair
    }
}
```

Now call Disconnect(list1).

That is recurse down list1 and disconnect pointers. When you reach end, execute step 2 (walk list2 to find junction), repair pointers when returning back from recursion.

This solution modifies list1 temporarily, so it is not thread safe and you should use a lock around the Disconnect(list1) call.

Answer (score 1):

//try this code for merge

```
   void mergeNode(){  
          node *copy,*current,*current1;

          free(copy);
      merge=NULL;
     current=head;
   current1=head1;
    while(current!=NULL){
    if(merge==NULL){
        node *tmp;
        tmp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        tmp->data=current->data;
        tmp->link=NULL;
        merge=tmp;
    }
    else{
        copy=merge;
        while(copy->link!=NULL)
            copy=copy->link;
        node *tmp;
        tmp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        tmp->data=current->data;
        tmp->link=copy->link;
        copy->link=tmp;
    }
    current=current->link;
}
while(current1!=NULL){
    copy=merge;
    while(copy->link!=NULL)
        copy=copy->link;
    node *tmp;
    tmp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    tmp->data=current1->data;
    tmp->link=copy->link;
    copy->link=tmp;
    current1=current1->link;
}
display(merge);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if my answer seems too simple, but if you have two linked list which are identified by a header and you join them, so that

`A -> B -> C -> D` is the first list, and

`1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4` is the second, then suppose

`A -> B -> C -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> D` is the result

then to find the merging point you need to go through the final list until you find the second header (the `1`). Which goes in O(n1) worst case, where n1 is the number of elements of the first list (this happens if the second list is merged at the end).

That's how I would intend the question. The reference to the C language would probably mean that you have no 'object' or pre-packaged data structure, unless specified.

[update] as suggested by Sebastian, if the two list above have the same elements my solution won't work. I suspect that this is where the C language comes into action: you can search for the **address** of the first element of the second list (the head). Thus the duplicates objection won't hold.

Comment: That doesn't work if the first list is A->A->A->A and the second list is A->A->B

Comment: @sebastian: you could as easily use the address (in memory) of the element. Thus there would be no case where A->A->A etc.

Comment: I know but your answer doesn't say that.

Comment: @sebastian: fair enough. answer has been updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are several approaches to solve this problem.

**Note that i am only discussing the approaches[`corner cases may need to be handled separately`] starting from brute force to the best one.**
Considering N: number of nodes in first linked list
            M: number of nodes in second linked list

**Approach 1:**
Compare each node of first linked list with every other node of second list. Stop when you find a matching node, this is the merging point.

```
while(head1)
{
cur2=head2;
while(cur2)
{
    if(cur2==head1)
        return cur2;
    cur2=cur2->next;
}
head1=head1->next;
}
```

**Time Complexity: O(N*M)

Space Complexity: O(1)**

**Approach 2:**
Maintain two stacks. Push all the nodes of he first linked list to first stack. Repeat he same for second linked list.
Start popping nodes from both the stacks until both popped nodes do not match. The last matching node is the merging point.
**Time Complexity: O(N+M)

Space Complexity: O(N+M)**

**Approach 3:**
Make use of hash table. Insert all the nodes of the first linked list into hash.
Search for the first matching node of he second list in the hash.
This is the merging point.
**Time Complexity: O(N+M)

Space Complexity: O(N)**
Note that the space complexity may vary depending upon the hash function used[talking about C where you are supposed to implement your own hash function].

**Approach 4:**
Insert all the nodes of first linked list[by nodes, i mean addresses] into an array.
Sort the array with some stable sorting algorithm in O(N logN) time[Merge sort would be better].
Now search for the first matching node from the second linked list.
**Time Complexity: O(N logN)

Space Complexity: O(N)**
Note that this approach may be better than `Approach 3` [in terms of space]as it doesn't use a hash.

**Approach 5:**
1. Take an array of size M+N.
2. Insert each node from the first linked list, followed by inserting each node from the second linked list.
3. Search for the first repeating element[can be found in one scan in O(M+N) time].
**Time Complexity: O(N+M)

Space Complexity: O(N+M)**

**Approach 6:**  [`A better approach`]
1. Modify the first linked list & make it circular.
2. Now starting from the head of the second linked list, find the start of the loop using `Floyd- Warshall cycle detection algorithm.`
3. Remove the loop[can be easily removed as we know the last node].
**Time Complexity: O(N+M)

Space Complexity: O(1)**

**Approach 7:**  [`Probably the best one`]
1. Count the number of nodes in first linked list[say c1].
2. Count the number of nodes in second linked list[say c2].
3. Find the difference[Lets say c1>c2] diff=c1-c2.
4. Take two pointers p1 & p2, p1 pointing to the head of the first linked list & p2 pointing to the head of the second linked list.
5. Move p1 diff times.
6. Move both p1 & p2 each node at a time until both point to the same node.
7. p1 or p2 indicates the merging point.
**Time Complexity: O(N+M)

Space Complexity: O(1)**

Answer (score 0):

Trivial solution is obviously O(N+M). Hm.. What could be better. You can go from start to end of the list or vice versa. When you have a threads, you can go these directions at the some time, so should be a litter bit quicker.